# recover woocommerce order from post_meta

Tags: woocommerce

I have some lost orders from my Woocommerce installation, found the deleted orders in the post_meta table. Can anyone please point me in a direction to recover these orders to the Woocommerce admin panel?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized and difficult to reproduce.